# When should I include URIs in my response body?

Tags: rest

If I have a resource /users and a resource /claims, such that /claims/7 returns this:

```
{ id: 7, text: "hello", postingUserID: 9 }
```

is that okay? Or should it be

```
{ id: 7, text: "hello", postingUserURI: "/users/9" }
```

I'd imagine the latter is more restful, but it's inconvenient because then I have to parse out the 9 if I want to do anything else with the ID.

Or perhaps I should have both?

```
{ id: 7, text: "hello", postingUserID: 9, postingUserURI: "/users/9" }
```

I like this one, but it's also a bit redundant.

What's the most restful thing to do? Thanks!

Comment: I was not involved in the closing of this question, but to have it reopened, I suggest instead of asking "which of these is best" type questions, it may be better to phrase it as "I am considering these options to fit this plan ... Are they each suitable? If not, please explain why before I select one." That way you are not asking for opinions, but facts. You leave the choice to yourself and will likely receive the same kinds of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most RESTful thing to do is to **include the URI.** The first option would not be very useful to a RESTful client as it represents a dead-end. A web browser is a great example of a restful client: option 1 is like serving a web page with no hyperlinks. The user has no means to advance the application state (browser tab), they can only read the page and then press their Back button.

**I would recommend option 2.** Clients should not have any need for IDs, as they can only be used for things like RPC-style HTTP requests generated using URI templates. This represents out-of-band information which is not REST. IDs are an internal implementation detail that need not be exposed. You need not even include the ID of the claim object. Anything you currently use IDs for in the client ought to be using hyperlinks received from the previous request.

As an example, my own API has a "Job Number", this number is an integer with no alphabetic part. I use an auto-incrementing ID field in my database to generate and save these job numbers, but when presenting them to clients, I present it as "Job Number" not a database ID. Clients do not use this for generating any future request, only for human-readable display.

When developing a new API, you might find it useful to output a HTML page that looks like your JSON response. Then navigate around it using a web browser. Every GET request should be generated by clicking on a hyperlink (anchor element) and not by typing IDs in the URL bar. This technique is known as *API Surfing.*

Unrelated to REST, I would change `postingUserURI` to `author` as the field name for the URI.